# Getting a text file with list of installed apps on iPhone or iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is there any simple way to get a list of all of the installed apps on my iPhone or iPad, that I can save to a text file?

I'm guessing it needs to be done from iTunes or an external app that manages iDevices. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

If your device is not jailbroken, there isn't much you can do to get a list, without doing some writing. That being said, there are many iDevice managers (such as iFunbox) that provide an easy interface.

**To see all of the apps on your phone with iFunbox:**

1. Open iFunbox.

   [image]
2. Connect your iOS device to your computer with a USB cable.
3. Select "Managing App Data" from the toolbar along the top of the window.

   [image]
4. Scroll down to the "All My Apps" section.

   [image]

Here. you find a nice grid of all the installed apps on your device.